# Unable to ignore class types in update-database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When we make an `update-database` with EF6 (v6.4.4), we want to ignore one class to be included at the end of the model creating stream.
Ex.

```
[NotMapped]
public class MyObjectType : MyObject, IMyObjectType {
..
}
```

We have tried using `[NotMapped]` annotation at the class definition without success and we also tried with the ignore extension method given the class name as a type, but again we have no success.
Ex.

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<MyObjectType>();
```

Can anyone suggest what we are doing wrong and maybe provide a short sample?

Comment: What makes EF *include* the class? Or: why is it necessary to unmap it?

Comment: It is some kind of temporary solution, later we want to include the class.

Comment: I meant to ask why EF incudes the class when you don't explicitly unmap it. EF doesn't map classes just like that, only if the class is configured to be mapped somehow.